# Embedding fillable PDF form in HTML, upload filled PDF

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I want to embed a fillable PDF file in HTML, have the user fill in the PDF (on the website to be seamless inside our service) and then upload the filled in PDF file to my backend.

I can't change the PDF itself, as it's a standardised document from a third party.

```
<embed id="pdfObject" src="link-to-pdf.com" type="application/pdf"></embed>
```

How can I use Javascript to access the modified PDF? I'd like to have an upload button, that uploads the modified PDF.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hm, it might be simpler to have a plain old HTML form and fill the data from that into the PDF in the backend; is that an option for you?

Comment: @JoelPeltonen thank you. Not really, as it's already partially filled and I would like to show the PDF itself to the user (lawyers who are used to that form as PDF not necessarily a HTML form)

Comment: There are many libraries that might help you accomplish this, [PDFNetJS](https://www.pdftron.com/blog/webviewer/pdfnetjs-html5-pdf-viewer-and-editor/) for example. However, they are often not free for commercial use. I recently built a rendition of a plaintiff fact sheet for a law firm and chose to have an html form that nearly exactly resembled the pdf, and sent the information to a server for processing.

Comment: I'm interested in a solution to this as well, especially if any open source packages are out there. If not I'm curious what paid software you decided to go with.